# Text Files Replacement Notepad++

Tags: list, file, text, replace, notepad++

I have 2 Text files.

First textfile:

```
A:12345
B:12346
C:12347
```

And second textfile:

```
12345:ZZZ
12346:QQQ
12347:WWW
```

I want to have a result textfile of:

```
A:ZZZ
B:QQQ
C:WWW
```

Can you guys help me how to get this solved?
I tried Notepad+++ but cant see how to make this automatically.
Because the list files have over 200k entries.

Answer (score 0):

I have no real answer but two ideas, both not based on an editor:

1. use Excel: import the two files as text, separated by : in two ranges and use vlookup function to combine them (imagine that the A,B,C are names, the ZZZ,QQQ,WWW are phone numbers and the 12345 are employee numbers, you want to lookup the phonenumber by the employee number). I don't know if the 200k lines are a problem, but once everything is in excel you could apply sort and filter on the two ranges and work first on the line starting with 1, then an the lines starting with 2.
2. if you are confident with sed, you could try to transform the second file into a sed script consisting of replacements like

   s/12345/ZZZ/g;
   s/12346/QQQ/g;
   ...

   and apply that script to the first file.

With best regards,
Lars